# KDB meta of all tables with table name displayed

Tags: kdb

Is there a way to display meta of all tables in tables[] along with table name?
I tried the following which displays all columns without table names.

```
raze meta each tables[]
```

| c | t f a |
| --- | --- |
| time | t s |
| sym | s g |
| col1 | s |
| col2 | p |
| col3 | s |
| col4 | b |

Is there a way to have table name displayed along with the meta of all?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You need to unkey before you raze using `0!` as meta returns keyed tables
- Add the table name in as a column `update tab:x from`
- `xcols` allows you to push the `tab` column to the left

```
q)t:([] a:1 2 3)
q)t1:([]b:4 5 6.0)
q)t2:([] c:``b`;c:("tf";"jj";"kk"))

q)`tab xcols raze {0!update tab:x from meta x}each tables[]
tab c  t f a
------------
t   a  j
t1  b  f
t2  c  s
t2  c1 C
```

- https://code.kx.com/q/ref/enkey/#unkey
- https://code.kx.com/q/ref/update/
- https://code.kx.com/q/ref/cols/#xcols